# Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficients (MFCC) in C/C++

Tags: speech-recognition, windowing, mfcc

Is there any implementation of MFCC available in C/C++? Any source codes or libraries?

I've already found http://code.google.com/p/libmfcc/ which seem to be good.

Answer (score 6):

A recap in 2016:

- `libmfcc` is simple, MIT license, unsupported since 2010.
- [YAAFE](http://yaafe.sourceforge.net/) provides MFCCs and other features, LGPLv3, unsupported since 2011.
- [Kaldi](http://kaldi-asr.org) is overkill, but it can be used just for the MFCC. Apache License v2.0, and still supported.
- [PocketSphinx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMU_Sphinx#PocketSphinx) is the CMU toolkit for speech recognition, CMU license (BSD-style), and still supported.
- [SPTK](http://sp-tk.sourceforge.net) is a research toolkit from Japan, Modified  BSD license, and still supported.
- [OpenSMILE](http://audeering.com/research/opensmile) has two licenses: (1) a flexible one for research and personal use, and (2) a commercial one.

Note I mention PocketSphinx, instead of Sphinx, as the latter is written in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the frontend from an open source speech recognition toolkit such as [Kaldi](http://kaldi.sourceforge.net/classkaldi_1_1Mfcc.html)
or [Sphinx](http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/code/11639/tree/trunk/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/).