# How to get MFCC from microphone input on android (C++, Qt)

Tags: android, c++, qt, mfcc

I am programming application on android and I am using Qt creator for this. I am looking for library, what samples signal, something like an Aquila. It needs MFCC technology. I will be grateful for all advices. Next thing is microphone. I have absolutely no idea, how I get any sounds for processing to the device. My idea is that I push button and microphone will record all sounds for 5 seconds and then get MFCC from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To record data in Qt you could use [QAudioRecorder](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiorecorder.html) and handle the event bufferReady to get the buffer data. You could find an easy example in my github:

https://github.com/mohabouje/logospeech-studio/blob/master/capturedata/recorder.h

If you are looking for some library to estimate the MFCC see this stack question: [Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficients (MFCC) in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124521/mel-frequency-cepstral-coefficients-mfcc-in-c-c)

I will recommend to implement our own algorith by using a basic FFT library, [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) is the best for me, easy & faster.

If you are looking for a complete set of audio signal processing i will recommend [Essentia Lib](http://essentia.upf.edu/)